# Multiple custom field sorting on wordpress archive page

Tags: wordpress

I have been through several topics on sorting taxonomies and custom fields, including some that were promising. However, I am still not constructing my query args correctly it seems.

I am "fixing" someone else's code in a custom theme that is used in a multisite configuration, but I am able to override/filter the query on a per-site basis.

The query is called via the theme with the following:

```html
return apply_filters( 'theme_query_args_filter', $args);
```

I have custom fields in the "role" taxonomy that include:

- last_name
- first_name

Pretty common I think.

However, when the args are executed, the following filter args are sorting only by last name (key part is the else clause):

```html
function my_args_filter( $args ) {
 
 if (is_home() && !is_search()) {
  $args['meta_key'] = 'event_date';
  $args['orderby'] = 'event_date';
  $args['order'] = 'DESC';
 }

else {
 $tax = $args['taxonomy'];
 $theterm = $args['term'];
 $args = array (
   'taxonomy' => $tax,
   'term' => $theterm,
   'meta_key' => 'last_name',
   'orderby' => 'meta_value',
   'order' => 'ASC'
  );
 
}

add_filter( 'theme_query_args_filter', 'my_args_filter' );
```

I've tried to modify the orderby as indicated in https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/08/29/a-more-powerful-order-by-in-wordpress-4-0/ to use an array to do a multisort, but I'm hitting my head up against the wall. I think the problem is that the code is written using a mixture of old ways of doing things and new ways.

Any advice is appreciated. According to the example on in the docs above, I SHOULD be able to pass in multiple meta key/value/orders via an array, but I'm just not getting it.

Thanks for any leads you might have. (long-time listener, first-time caller)

(I also looked at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/109849/order-by-desc-asc-in-custom-wp-query but I couldn't extrapolate that example to this one either)

Comment: take look at this link 

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out on my most recent try.  Hat tip to this solution https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/249881/multiple-custom-fields-for-orderby-in-wp-query by Nath. if there is a more elegant way to do it, please let me know.

```
$tax = $args['taxonomy'];
    $theterm = $args['term'];
    $paged = $args['paged'];
    $args = array (
            'taxonomy' => $tax,
            'term' => $theterm,
            'paged' => $paged,
            'posts_per_page' => '10',
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    'last_name' => 
                        array(
                            'key' => 'last_name',
                            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
                            ),
                    'first_name' => 
                        array(
                            'key' => 'first_name',
                            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
                    ),
                ),
        ),
            'orderby' => array (
                'last_name' => 'ASC',
                'first_name' => 'ASC',

        )
        );

}
```